# Stop python thread that contains blocking loop

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to design object oriented interface to ZeroMQ.

I wan't to use zmq receiver in my processes but I don't want it to block the process with it's loop. So I'm trying to start loop in another thread.

```
class BaseZmqReceiver(BaseZmqNode):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, host, port, hwm, bind, on_receive_callback):
        super(BaseZmqReceiver, self).__init__(host=host, port=port, bind=bind, hwm=hwm)
        self.node.on_message_callback = on_receive_callback
        self.stream = ZMQStream(self.socket)
        self.stream.on_recv(self.on_message_received)
        ZmqLoopRunner().start()

    def on_message_received(self, message):
        return self.node.on_message_callback(message)

    def create_node(self):
        return ReceivingNode(None, None)

class ZmqLoopRunner(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ZmqLoopRunner, self).__init__()
        self.loop = IOLoop.instance()

    def run(self):
        self.loop.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.loop.stop()
```

But I don't know how to properly stop this thread, because the loop.start() method is blocking.
How can I do that?

Comment: Is it about Tornado, btw?

Comment: I don't use tornado loop explicitely. IOLoop here isfrom zmq.eventloop import IOLoop

Comment: add_callback (http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/api/generated/zmq.eventloop.ioloop.html) in 0mq is totally the same as in Tornado. I belive you can use approach #2.

Comment: Um... Unfortunately I still don't get it. What should I do to stop the loop at any moment?

Comment: Can you show me some code? Because I have a lot of questions about that.

Answer (score 1):

1) If it's about Tornado IOLoop (*update: it is not*), The Right Way is to [use the nonblocking integration](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/multisocket/tornadoeventloop.html) inside a single IOLoop.

2) To stop an IOLoop by hand, one calls `IOLoop.instance().stop()` from the IOLoop thread:

```
IOLoop.instance().add_callback(IOLoop.instance().stop)
```

`add_callback()` makes sure that stop() method is called inside the IOLoop event thread, and IOLoop is stopped cleanly.

In your code this would be:

```
class BaseZmqReceiver(BaseZmqNode):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, host, port, hwm, bind, on_receive_callback):
        super(BaseZmqReceiver, self).__init__(
            host=host, port=port, bind=bind, hwm=hwm)
        # ...
        self.zmq_runner = ZmqLoopRunner()
        # this will start a new thread.
        self.zmq_runner.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.zmq_runner.stop()

class ZmqLoopRunner(Thread):
    # ...
    def stop(self):
        """ 
        Call this from any thread, add_callback() will make sure 
        it runs in IOLoop thread.
        """
        self.loop.add_callback(self.loop.stop)  # Note the absence of parentheses
```

3) If you need the thread to exit on program shutdown, you can [make it daemon](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects). Even more wrong, as it won't cleanly shut down the `IOLoop`.

```
class ZmqLoopRunner(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ZmqLoopRunner, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = True
```

Comment: What is 'nonblocking integration'?

Comment: I thought that you're running both 0mq and Tornado. Both their `IOLoop`s are built on a nonblocking code. If there was an integration library that integrated their event loops, that would be a preferable way opposed to spawning a thread. IOLoop is actually designed to completely eliminate poor Python threads.

Comment: Can you please show me some code on how you think it should be done in right way? So that process that has a handler function wouldn't be blocked by zmq receiver and would be decoupled from zmq.
Because all I can see is that loop.start() method is blocking. And If I would use zmq receiver in some process it would block it.